# Run another command if there is any input on the standard input

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

How can I run another command if there is any input on the standard input

commonly used in situations like this:

some command with no normal output | ifinput mail -s 'some output' me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be using a file (if you dare!).
The `-s` switch means "file is not zero size". The `&>` redirections includes errors as well (means that stdout and stderr will be sent).

```
OUTFILE=/tmp/command.out
some command &> $OUTFILE
[ -s "$OUTFILE" ] && mail -s "subject here" email@example.com < "$OUTFILE"
```

Edit: the comment below by glenn jackman contains even a better solution.

Comment: Don't really need a file for that: `output=$(some command); [[ -n "$output" ]] && mail ... <<< "$output"`

Answer (score 3):

A little trickery with `read`:

```
$ echo 1 | { read -t 0 -N 0 && cat ; } 
1
$ { read -t 0 -N 0 && cat ; } 
$
```

Comment: Hmm looks promising - can you show an example sending "1" to the mail command? In your example, would I just replace cat with the command that I wanted to run?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a shell script. That script could first call some command that redirects the output to a file and then call the mail command from within the script to send it out which is essentially what SamKrieg is doing without the need to create a shell script.  A reason for the script may depend on if you want to run this command as a cron job or somehting.